# Find path of storage in Android

Tags: android

The application that am working has to access the files stored
on a tablet in the internal storage folder. Can any one tell me
how to get access to it?

Comment: I am not sure but something like, Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this?

```
return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Music";
```

Answer (score 1):

See [internal storage section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) of android [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) document..

## EDIT

I think you should use [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html)..Personally I never tried this..

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
File directory = cw.getDir("your music folder name here", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

please check directory is null or not before you use it..

## EDIT

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715556/cant-find-the-file-stored-on-internal-storage-of-device-on-file-explorer) thread..this might help you

Comment: Hi actually i want to get the path of music folder in tablet device. not for my app internal folder

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState());
```

Comment: Why not simply using `File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`? The fewer objects created, the better.